# Fixing problem with multiple versions of dependencies in Tycho

Tags: java, maven, dependencies, tycho

I'm converting a legacy Java application buidl system to build with Maven and Tycho. I'm currently building an eclipse product file. The individual plugins and features that make up the product build with tycho. But once tycho tries to resolve the dependencies for the product I receive the error message:

```
[ERROR] Cannot resolve project dependencies:
[ERROR]   Software being installed: at.jku.mevss.monitoringmanager 1.0.0.qualifier
[ERROR]   Only one of the following can be installed at once: [org.eclipse.equinox.registry 3.8.100.v20180827-1235, org.eclipse.equinox.registry 3.6.100.v20160223-2218, org.eclipse.equinox.registry 3.5.200.v20120522-1841, org.eclipse.equinox.registry 3.5.400.v20140428-1507, org.eclipse.equinox.registry 3.5.100.v20110502, org.eclipse.equinox.registry 3.6.0.v20150318-1503]
[ERROR]   Only one of the following can be installed at once: [org.eclipse.ui 3.103.0.v20120705-114351, org.eclipse.ui 3.8.0.v20120523-1546, org.eclipse.ui 3.107.0.v20150507-1945, org.eclipse.ui 3.108.1.v20160929-1045, org.eclipse.ui 3.104.0.v20121024-145224, org.eclipse.ui 3.8.2.v20121018-234953, org.eclipse.ui 3.110.0.v20180828-1350, org.eclipse.ui 3.7.0.I20110602-0100, org.eclipse.ui 3.103.0.v20120521-2329, org.eclipse.ui 3.106.0.v20140519-0906]
[ERROR]   Cannot satisfy dependency: at.jku.mevss.idetools.rcp.feature.feature.group 0.1.0.qualifier depends on: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu; org.eclipse.core.runtime.compatibility.registry 0.0.0
[ERROR]   Cannot satisfy dependency: at.jku.mevss.monitoringmanager 1.0.0.qualifier depends on: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu; at.jku.mevss.idetools.rcp.feature.feature.group 0.0.0
[ERROR]   Cannot satisfy dependency: at.jku.mevss.monitoringmanager 1.0.0.qualifier depends on: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu; at.jku.mevss.util.feature.feature.group 0.0.0
[ERROR]   Cannot satisfy dependency: at.jku.mevss.monitoringmanager 1.0.0.qualifier depends on: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu; org.eclipse.platform.feature.group 0.0.0
[ERROR]   Cannot satisfy dependency: at.jku.mevss.ui.util 1.0.0.qualifier depends on: osgi.bundle; org.jfree.jfreechart 0.0.0
[ERROR]   Cannot satisfy dependency: at.jku.mevss.util.feature.feature.group 0.4.0.qualifier depends on: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu; at.jku.mevss.ui.util 0.0.0
[ERROR]   Cannot satisfy dependency: org.eclipse.core.runtime.compatibility.registry 3.5.100.v20120521-2346 depends on: osgi.bundle; org.eclipse.equinox.registry [3.5.0,3.6.0)
[ERROR]   Cannot satisfy dependency: org.eclipse.core.runtime.compatibility.registry 3.5.101.v20130108-163257 depends on: osgi.bundle; org.eclipse.equinox.registry [3.5.0,3.6.0)
[ERROR]   Cannot satisfy dependency: org.eclipse.platform.feature.group 3.8.0.v20120607-071945-9gF7jI7nG5qByXMVdkhRMWBQlF4PnDCLybDCPQ depends on: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu; org.eclipse.rcp.feature.group [3.8.0.v20120528-1716-92BmGJTFw3Ez0W7_KvHqgZUR,3.8.0.v20120528-1716-92BmGJTFw3Ez0W7_KvHqgZUR]
[ERROR]   Cannot satisfy dependency: org.eclipse.platform.feature.group 3.8.1.v20120815-074604-9gF7jI7wG5qDyZMWGg8NPvDbfWFWlIJU-kYaOQ depends on: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu; org.eclipse.rcp.feature.group [3.8.1.v20120814-105048-92BmGJlFw3Ez0WZ9TxCqgcSVAE,3.8.1.v20120814-105048-92BmGJlFw3Ez0WZ9TxCqgcSVAE]
[ERROR]   Cannot satisfy dependency: org.eclipse.platform.feature.group 3.8.1.v20130118-180812-9jF7oIBFG8eU2pim-VbIlTuQjY0RWWK3x-bv4I depends on: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu; org.eclipse.rcp.feature.group [3.8.2.v20130118-180157-96BuGOZFxwOAeG8Ofmqicz0tPK,3.8.2.v20130118-180157-96BuGOZFxwOAeG8Ofmqicz0tPK]
[ERROR]   Cannot satisfy dependency: org.eclipse.platform.feature.group 4.2.0.v20120608-135145-9JF7BHV8FyMteji0Oi_ePMz0xuZ8TVo7lV0z0ecb depends on: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu; org.eclipse.rcp.feature.group [4.2.0.v20120528-1648-7IAPA7BrHQicRpNdOz-Obz-rlRCA,4.2.0.v20120528-1648-7IAPA7BrHQicRpNdOz-Obz-rlRCA]
[ERROR]   Cannot satisfy dependency: org.eclipse.platform.feature.group 4.2.1.v20120814-120134-9JF7BHVGFyMveli1uX6aTH0q-eAap6PAgOP5mO depends on: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu; org.eclipse.rcp.feature.group [4.2.1.v20120814-120134-7IAPA8BrHQicS-rjP0GbqK780kMy,4.2.1.v20120814-120134-7IAPA8BrHQicS-rjP0GbqK780kMy]
[ERROR]   Cannot satisfy dependency: org.eclipse.platform.feature.group 4.2.1.v20130118-173121-9MF7GHYdG0B5kx4E_SkfZV-1mNjVATf67ZAb7 depends on: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu; org.eclipse.rcp.feature.group [4.2.2.v20130129-152330-7IARAABrMQkGSvMgQnUlz-DQz00h,4.2.2.v20130129-152330-7IARAABrMQkGSvMgQnUlz-DQz00h]
[ERROR]   Cannot satisfy dependency: org.eclipse.platform.feature.group 4.6.3.v20170301-0400 depends on: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu; org.eclipse.ui.intro.quicklinks [1.0.0.v20160515-0255,1.0.0.v20160515-0255]
[ERROR]   Cannot satisfy dependency: org.eclipse.platform.feature.group 4.9.0.v20180906-1121 depends on: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu; org.eclipse.urischeme [1.0.0.v20180828-1120,1.0.0.v20180828-1120]
[ERROR]   Cannot satisfy dependency: org.eclipse.rcp.feature.group 3.8.0.v20120528-1716-92BmGJTFw3Ez0W7_KvHqgZUR depends on: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu; org.eclipse.ui [3.8.0.v20120523-1546,3.8.0.v20120523-1546]
[ERROR]   Cannot satisfy dependency: org.eclipse.rcp.feature.group 3.8.1.v20120814-105048-92BmGJlFw3Ez0WZ9TxCqgcSVAE depends on: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu; org.eclipse.ui [3.8.0.v20120523-1546,3.8.0.v20120523-1546]
[ERROR]   Cannot satisfy dependency: org.eclipse.rcp.feature.group 3.8.2.v20130118-180157-96BuGOZFxwOAeG8Ofmqicz0tPK depends on: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu; org.eclipse.ui [3.8.2.v20121018-234953,3.8.2.v20121018-234953]
[ERROR]   Cannot satisfy dependency: org.eclipse.rcp.feature.group 4.2.0.v20120528-1648-7IAPA7BrHQicRpNdOz-Obz-rlRCA depends on: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu; org.eclipse.ui [3.103.0.v20120521-2329,3.103.0.v20120521-2329]
[ERROR]   Cannot satisfy dependency: org.eclipse.rcp.feature.group 4.2.1.v20120814-120134-7IAPA8BrHQicS-rjP0GbqK780kMy depends on: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu; org.eclipse.ui [3.103.0.v20120705-114351,3.103.0.v20120705-114351]
[ERROR]   Cannot satisfy dependency: org.eclipse.rcp.feature.group 4.2.2.v20130129-152330-7IARAABrMQkGSvMgQnUlz-DQz00h depends on: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu; org.eclipse.ui [3.104.0.v20121024-145224,3.104.0.v20121024-145224]
[ERROR]   Cannot satisfy dependency: org.eclipse.ui.intro.quicklinks 1.0.0.v20160515-0255 depends on: osgi.bundle; org.eclipse.equinox.registry 3.6.100
[ERROR]   Cannot satisfy dependency: org.eclipse.urischeme 1.0.0.v20180828-1120 depends on: osgi.bundle; org.eclipse.equinox.registry [3.8.0,4.0.0)
[ERROR]   Cannot satisfy dependency: org.jfree.jfreechart 1.0.13.201902282149 depends on: osgi.bundle; org.eclipse.ui 3.107.0
```

I have gone through all relevant Manifest files and set all `require-bundle` entries as `3.8.0 with match=greaterOrEqual`, which didn't yield any results.
Could it be, that the issue arises from transitive dependencies? If yes, how can I find out which dependencies generate the problem, and how can I resolve them? I have added quite a few p2 repositories due to a big amount of dependencies that I am trying to resolve via p2 repositories, so the build might be able to access various different versions of eclipse packages. Could this be an issue here?

Also the jfreechart dependency is the only one available via a p2 repository, and requires a way newer version of `org.eclipse.ui` Than the rest of the project, and also with a fixed version number. Could this be an issue, and is there a way to generate this dependency as an eclipse bundle from a maven bundle that has previously no information it's manifest during the build?

When creating the dependency tree for the project I can see, that some projects require different versions. Those dependencies are not shown as being transitive though, and I haven't specifically set them, so I don't know where the version requirement is originating from.

Comment: I would try just using the most recent Eclipse repository (4.9.0 from the look of this). Also trying to mix Eclipse 3 and Eclipse 4 repositories is not likely to work as there was a major rewrite for Eclipse 4.

Comment: @greg-449 Thanks for the answer! Unfortunately this project relies on a couple of legacy dependencies which are not present in more recent repos. It also includes some code that will not compile for Eclipse 4 because of the rewrite you mentioned. I will try to not use the newer repositories.

Comment: If you have stuff that only compiles on Eclipse 3 you will have to use just Eclipse 3 for everything, just use the 3.8.1 repository.